# Laravel5.5 can't Install Image/Intervention

Tags: php, laravel, package

I just need some help I try to install image/intervention into my project, but got the problem message as the image below: 
[image: Problem1]
Do I have to upgrade PHP VERSION to a higher one?

I am really appreciated if you can help me solve this problem.

Thank You
Siripong

Comment: it's a self explanatory, your php version is not compatible with the package requirements, you will need to upgrade your php version , or use a lower version of the package css-selector that works fine with your php version.

Comment: Okay I see, do you know how to upgrade PHP version?

Comment: Install new version of Xampp

Comment: Since you are using WAMP, check on wampserver website (or here) how to backup projects and databases and upgrade to newest WAMP version which has PHP 7.1.9 prebuilt.

Comment: Please post the text of your error, not a screenshot, that way others searching for the same error will be able to find this question and the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of your htdocs and data folder (subfolder of MySQL folder), reinstall upgraded version of **xampp** and replace those folders.

N.B. Don't forget to take backup of your project in htdocs.

Answer (score 0):

When you visit https://packagist.org/packages/intervention/image you can see that the requirement is php >=5.4.0 so all good here. I think is the dependencies that need a higher php version. The temporary solution may be, to downgrade the package to version 2.3 or even lower so you can make sure that the old versions are working. They need to fix the package if this is the case and if it is working for you with a lower version maybe you can used it like that, but depends on what your app needs.